# I want to get unix time on Firebird

Tags: firebird

iwant to get the time in firebird similar to GetTime on Javascript 
i have created one but its not that accurate the time difference increment everyday

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETTIMEINMILLISECONDS
RETURNS (
  MILL VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE VAR_PARAM INTEGER;
BEGIN
select
(((extract(year from current_timestamp)
  -extract(year from cast('01/01/1970 00:00:00' as timestamp))) *  31536000000) +
(extract(month from current_timestamp) * 2592000000) +
(extract(day from current_timestamp)   *  8640000) +
(extract(Hour from current_timestamp)   * 3600000) +
 (extract(minute from current_timestamp) * 60000) +
  (extract(second from current_timestamp) * 1000))-192960000
  from rdb$database  into :Mill;
  suspend;
END
;
```

Comment: Related (the reverse operation): [How to convert from Unix time to datetime in Firebird?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669717/how-to-convert-from-unix-time-to-datetime-in-firebird)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Firebird 2.1 and higher you can use

```
select DATEDIFF(second, timestamp '1/1/1970 00:00:00', current_timestamp)
from rdb$database
```

For earlier version you can use the UDF F_AGEINSECONDS from FreeAdhocUDF:

```
select F_AGEINSECONDS('1/1/1970 00:00:00', current_timestamp) from
rdb$database
```

See [Re: [firebird-support] How to convert TIMESTAMP to unix timestamp (number of seconds since epoch)](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2009/6/102699.html)

You will need to account for your current timezone by adding the timezone offset to the timestamp if you are not in GMT. For exampe, for CEST (+2:00), you will need to use:

```
select DATEDIFF(second, timestamp '1970-01-01 02:00:00', current_timestamp)
from rdb$database
```

(note I switched to ISO-8601 date format here)

In Firebird 4.0 you can avoid this correction by using a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` literal:

```
select DATEDIFF(second, timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', current_timestamp)
from rdb$database
```

Comment: changing my current time zone help a lot, this code is great select DATEDIFF(second, timestamp '1/1/1970 08:00:00',    current_timestamp) *1000
from rdb$database  into :Mill;

Comment: Unix time is seconds since 1970-01-01, so there should be no need to multiply by thousand (and if you need it in milliseconds [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-datediff.html) also supports `MILLISECOND`.