# How to convert from Unix time to datetime in Firebird?

Tags: firebird, datetime-format, unix-timestamp

Does Firebird have something similar to MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME` function for converting Unix time to datetime?

Comment: Related (the reverse operation): [I want to get unix time on Firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850811/i-want-to-get-unix-time-on-firebird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no separate built-in function to do this in Firebird. The solution is to use [`DATEADD`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-dateadd) against the epoch:

```sql
dateadd(<your-unix-timestamp> second to timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

or

```sql
dateadd(second, <your-unix-timestamp>, timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```

For example:

```
SQL> select dateadd(1655563246 second to timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00') from rdb$database;

                  DATEADD
=========================
2022-06-18 14:40:46.0000
```

Important caveat: the result is a `TIMESTAMP`, which is without timezone. Interpretation varies by platform (e.g. Java will interpret it in the current JVM timezone). In Firebird 4.0, you can make it a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` at UTC by using `timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'` instead.